# How to share on twitter using twitter API?

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-oauth

for sharing on twitter using oath API my code is below:

```
NSURL* accessTokenUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"];
OAMutableURLRequest* accessTokenRequest = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:accessTokenUrl consumer:consumer token:requestToken realm:nil signatureProvider:nil];
OARequestParameter* verifierParam = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"oauth_verifier" value:verifier];

[accessTokenRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


[accessTokenRequest setValue:@"Test"    forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Twitter-Client"];
[accessTokenRequest setValue:@"1.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Twitter-Client-Version"];
[accessTokenRequest setValue:callback     forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Twitter-Client-URL"];

[accessTokenRequest setParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:verifierParam]];
OADataFetcher* dataFetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
[dataFetcher fetchDataWithRequest:accessTokenRequest
                         delegate:self
                didFinishSelector:@selector(didReceiveRequestToken:data2:)
                  didFailSelector:@selector(didFailOAuth:error:)];
```

But I am getting response below:
 {"errors":[{"message":"Invalid or expired token","code":89}]}

But my token is valid and not expired as I am getting user's profile successfully from this.
So can anyone help me what I am missing in this code?

Comment: try to create new tocken

Comment: @Amy But using same accesstoken I am getting user's profile. If its expired how I get profile?

Comment: @Pooja: Twitter documentation is very well explained, you can find solution here https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing

Comment: @Mrunal I have done same flow, still not working.

Comment: You should check with your token expiration, on dev.twitter.com. Is it still valid or require to revoke.

Answer (score 0):

// plz try this code..

```
-(IBAction)ShareOnTwitter :(id)sender
{

UIButton *btn4=(UIButton *)sender;
int count = (int)btn4.tag;
NSLog(@"ShareOnTwitter count=%d",count);

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.jpg",Pathforimage,[[Array_result objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey:@"img_File_Name"]]];

if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {

    SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

    SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result)
    {
        if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled)
        {
                    NSLog(@"Cancelled");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Done");
        }
        [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
    };
    controller.completionHandler =myBlock;

    //Adding the Text to the twitter post value from iOS
    [controller setInitialText:@""];

    //Adding the Image to the twitter post value from iOS
    [controller addImage:image];

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"UnAvailable");
}
}
```

Comment: check my question, I want using API.